# WebView and Advanced View is Not loading partiucalr URL

Tags: android, webview

I try to load one particular URL on the Android web view and it is keep on throwing error as i attached in the screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmIrk.png):

Code here

```
 mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
        CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);

        settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        settings.setSupportZoom(true);
        settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        settings.setUserAgentString(AppConstant.USER_AGENT);

        mWebView.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();
        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        mWebView.setInitialScale(30);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

  if (mFindPricesURL.contains(".pdf")) {
            try {
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + mFindPricesURL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                launchDocumentViewer(mFindPricesURL);
            }
        } else if (mFindPricesURL.contains(".xls") || mFindPricesURL.contains(".ppt")
                || mFindPricesURL.contains(".doc")) {
            launchDocumentViewer("https://m.goodrx.com/search");
        } else {
            mWebView.loadUrl(mFindPricesURL);
        }
```

Also i did

```
 private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            ProgressBarUtil.dismissProgressDialog();
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('imPage').style.display='none';");
        }

    }
```

[image: Error in web View]

as mention in the code i have enabled the cookie and Java script in Webview i dono what additionally that we have to do on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Solution that we have to implement the WebView JavaScript Interface for above API level 17

```
public class WebAppInterface {
Context mContext;

/** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
WebAppInterface(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

/** Show a toast from the web page */
@JavascriptInterface
public void showToast(String toast) {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} }
```

Caution: If you've set your targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher, you must add the @JavascriptInterface annotation to any method that you want available to your JavaScript (the method must also be public). If you do not provide the annotation, the method is not accessible by your web page when running on Android 4.2 or higher.

**See here how to implement**: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview

Answer (score 0):

I found you are using `mWebView.getSettings().getJavaScriptEnabled();` but you have to call `settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

you have to call `settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);` when you calling `setAppCacheEnabled`

and for cookies you can call `CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);`

**Update code**

The full code base will be:

```
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDefaultFontSize(utils.getTextSize());
settings.setDefaultFixedFontSize(utils.getTextSize());
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
settings.setSaveFormData(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
String ua = "";
String[] buildNumber = FINGERPRINT.split("/");
if (SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

       ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android " + API + "; en-us; Build/" + FINGERPRINT + ") AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.30";
  } else if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android " + API + "; " + MODEL + " Build/" + buildNumber[3] + ") AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36";
} else {
      ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android " + API + "; " + MODEL + " Build/" + buildNumber[3] + ") AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/73.0.3683.90 Mobile Safari/537.36";

  }

getSettings().setUserAgentString(ua);
```

here :

```
private static final String API = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
private static final String MODEL = Build.MODEL;
private static final String FINGERPRINT = Build.FINGERPRINT;
private static final String FINGERPRINT = Build.FINGERPRINT;
```

Comment: I modified my code with what you have mentioned above. Again i am getting the **same error**.

Comment: You can try this also if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {   
     CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView, true);
} else {
     CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
}

Comment: Did you put any code in your **MyBrowser** class like: **shouldInterceptRequest**  override method??

Comment: **Tried again getting the same Error!!** i can able load all the web url except this one url ("https://m.goodrx.com/search")

Comment: No i have not added such kind of method in MyBrowser class

Comment: ok i tried your url with different settings and work. Its long method: so i updated my answer

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can test it. I hope it will be work

Comment: Thank you will check and let you know

Comment: I have tested with the above code. Again i am getting the **same problem**

Comment: Did you replace your existing settings code with my new code?